# Implement rdd.me api in UIWebView

Tags: ios, api, uiwebview, rss, readability

I'm working on an app which load newsarticles into a UIWebView from RSS. But I want the users to get a better reading experience and want to implement the rdd.me api. I haven't found any good guides to implement this api into a ios application and hope someone here can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This project](https://github.com/Fahrni/RFRddMe) on github is an Objective-C wrapper of rdd.me APIs.

It also has some instructions on how to use it.

Comment: Thanks! But do you know about a iOSproject? for iPhone?

Comment: I don't know whether the author has added the iOS target, but you can add an issue on github and ask for it ;)

Comment: Ok, I will take a look in Github :)